# In Google Sheets, why does rank() treat two identical values differently?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, ranking-functions

I have a sheet with four values that I believe are all equal (i.e. `=A1=B1` returns `TRUE` for each pair). However, when I use `rank()` on a list with those values, they receive different ranks.
To my knowledge, I'm not doing anything strange, such as a workaround to avoid duplicates. (In this scenario, I want duplicate ranks.)  The values I'm trying to `rank()` were the result of a `trunc(sum(...),1)`, so there aren't any hidden decimals places that I'm not noticing.

I'm just using `rank(A1,A1:B1)` and `arrayformula(rank(A1:B1,A1:B1)`. These two formulas return different results, even.

Why is `rank()` treating these numbers as different? Is there some kind of flag or extra property on the cells that's not normally visible that is making them different?

This situation is a little hard to explain without seeing the data, so I've recreated the situation in this sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cL_15WnKgrxhJfT5lYYIg4sRAzaAzbpP7nH9hju1Rv4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the [`Floating Point Error`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) than with `RANK`.

In any case and since you are trying to see if *" ...there aren't any hidden decimals places that's I'm not noticing"* you could follow a different approach.

- Using the [`ROUND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093440) function, round the values of your `trunc(sum(...),1)` results to however many decimal places you may need. **OR**
- From the top menu choose `Format`> `Number`> `More formats`> `Custom number formats` and create your own

[image]

---

**Following that, you will be able to visually spot the differences.

Additionally you can use the [`RANK`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094098) function**

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Adding `round()` to my data cleared the original problem I was having with ranking.